# Problem with hard drive. Hardware failure?

Tags: linux

I am running a linux server in my home. The server has 4 * 2TB hard drives, running snapraid for parity. Each drive is mounted seperately, united to one drive with mergerfs.

Today I notice that one drive is mounted read only. Some investigation later, I changed one SATA cable and switched SATA ports, but it didn't solve the problem.

After every restart, the drive is working for couple of minutes, then I/O errors occur and it's mounted read only. FSCK already run, fixed some errors, was clean.

Everything is backed up, and additionally there is the parity drive from snapraid. I wonder if this drive is broken, because its the youngest one in my server (oldest is twice as old).

So, what should I do? Replace? I'm thinking of replacing all drives with 3*4TB to prevent future failures. I am afraid more drives will break in near future.

Cheers and thx for reply

```
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.117220] ata5.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x80 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.117314] ata5.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.117374] ata5.00: cmd 60/00:38:78:32:56/01:00:e4:00:00/40 tag 7 ncq dma 131072 in
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.117374]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.117507] ata5.00: status: { DRDY }
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.117550] ata5: hard resetting link
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.432312] ata5: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.434545] ata5.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.434551] ata5.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.434555] ata5.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.437078] ata5.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.437083] ata5.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.437087] ata5.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.437657] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.437687] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#28 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_TIMEOUT
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.437695] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#28 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 74 44 4a d0 00 00 08 00
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.437699] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 1950632656
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.437851] Aborting journal on device dm-2-8.
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.437868] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#29 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_TIMEOUT
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.437920] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#29 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 e4 56 31 78 00 01 00 00
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.437924] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 3830854008
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.438073] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#19 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_TIMEOUT
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.438079] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#19 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 0b 02 67 20 00 00 08 00
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.438082] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 184706848
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.438214] EXT4-fs error (device dm-2) in ext4_da_write_begin:3113: IO failure
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.438216] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#6 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_TIMEOUT
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.438223] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#6 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 30 27 0a 00 00 02 00 00
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.438304] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 807864832
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.438440] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#5 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_TIMEOUT
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.438446] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#5 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 30 27 08 00 00 02 00 00
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.438449] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 807864320
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.438592] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#7 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.438598] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#7 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.438605] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#7 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.438610] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#7 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 e4 56 32 78 00 01 00 00
Oct  5 19:18:38 storage kernel: [ 2534.438614] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 3830854264
```

```
smartctl 6.6 2017-11-05 r4594 [x86_64-linux-4.19.0-16-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-17, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital AV-GP (AF)
Device Model:     WDC WD20EURX-63T0FY0
Serial Number:    WD-WCC4M1933067
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 209c98f92
Firmware Version: 80.00A80
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Oct  5 20:25:48 2021 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x85) Offline data collection activity
                    was aborted by an interrupting command from host.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (26940) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 272) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x7035) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   199   199   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       4331
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   174   172   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       4258
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       2448
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   078   078   000    Old_age   Always       -       16390
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       54
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       43
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       2405
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   122   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       25
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       194

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 1
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 1 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 606 hours (25 days + 6 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  04 51 01 00 00 00 00  Error: ABRT

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  b0 d5 01 e1 4f c2 00 08   1d+14:10:24.946  SMART READ LOG
  b0 d5 01 00 4f c2 00 08   1d+14:10:24.946  SMART READ LOG
  b0 d6 01 e0 4f c2 00 08   1d+14:10:24.946  SMART WRITE LOG
  b0 d6 01 e0 4f c2 00 08   1d+14:10:24.945  SMART WRITE LOG
  b0 d5 01 e0 4f c2 00 08   1d+14:10:24.944  SMART READ LOG

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     16380         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     16356         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     16333         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     16305         -
# 5  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     16299         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     16237         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     16213         -
# 8  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     16198         -
# 9  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     16116         -
#10  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     16092         -
#11  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     16074         -
#12  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     16046         -
#13  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     16022         -
#14  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     15994         -
#15  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     15974         -
#16  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     15950         -
#17  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     15924         -
#18  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     15902         -
#19  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     15874         -
#20  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     15852         -
#21  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     15832         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: smart is relatively clean, please run `sudo smartctl -t long /dev/sdd` though you must be aware that this operation can potentially destroy the data on it for good if the disk is indeed failing.

Comment: You've already tried a different cable and ports and run fsck which gave errors. The only thing that's left to do is to try the drives in a known working system but everything already points to the drives failing. Running more utilities will just add wear to the drive. Everything is backed up so it's best to just replace the drives. Keep in mind that different drives won't prevent failure. Nothing will. The only thing that you can do is to continue your good habit of making sure that the data is backed up.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback guys. I replaced the disk with 2 x 4TB drives and could successfully restore all data on the "going to be bad" drive.

After this I run a bad blocks test and there are 6 bb. Do you think the drive is still usable as backup drive for cold backup? Or should I throw it?

Current_Pending_Sector says 13.